# How to know which field is missed while parsing json in Json4s

Tags: json, scala, exception, akka, json4s

I have made a generic method which parses json to case class and it also works fine. But if tries to parse big json which have one or two mandatory field then I am not able to figure out which particular mandatory f ield is missing. I am only able to handle it with IllegalArgumentException. Is there a way to handle to know which is field is missing while parsing Json by using json4s.

Here is my code ->

```
object JsonHelper {

  implicit val formats: DefaultFormats = DefaultFormats

  def write[T <: AnyRef](value: T): String = jWrite(value)

  def parse(value: String): JValue = jParser(value)

}
```

And this is the method I am using to parse Json and handle failed case ->

```
def parseJson[M](json: String)(implicit m: Manifest[M]): Either[ErrorResponse, M] = {
    try
      Right(JsonHelper.parse(json).extract[M])
    catch {
      case NonFatal(th) =>
        th.getCause.getCause match {
          case e: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException =>
            error(s"Invalid JSON - $json", e)
            Left(handle(exception = EmptyFieldException(e.getMessage.split(":").last)))
          case _ =>
            error(s"Invalid JSON - $json", th)
            Left(handle(exception = new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Json", th)))
        }
    }
  }
```

Like for a Json ->

```
{
   "name": "Json"
}
```

And case class ->

```
case class(name: String, profession: String)
```

if I try to parse above json into case class currently I am getting `Invalid JSON - IllegalArgumentException`. But is there a way that the exception tells which is field is missing like in above example `"profession"` is missing.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. [Just in case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75432474), normally you can just edit your "deleted" question and undelete it rather than delete and submit a new version.

Comment: Noted your point

Comment: Please provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that it's possible to understand what your actual problem is. Now your code is not self-contained and that's why it doesn't compile

Comment: *"I am only able to handle it with IllegalArgumentException"* Why?

Comment: Normally `IllegalArgumentException` should be followed by `Caused by: org.json4s.MappingException` with the field name. Isn't it? Is it swallowed somewhere? If you catch `IllegalArgumentException` somewhere outside (`try {...} catch { case e: IllegalArgumentException => ... }`) what is in `e.getCause`, `e.getSuppressed`, `e.getStackTrace`?

Comment: Can you make fields optional? `case class MyClass(name: String, profession: Option[String])`

Comment: Yes I can but the above Json is just for example, If for some reason I have a big Json then with multiple mandatory field, I want to Know which field is missing from Json that it was not able to parse into case class.

Comment: Try to look into `IllegalArgumentException` stacktrace as I proposed or please provide MCVE

Comment: Why do you have so weird exception handling `th.getCause.getCause...`? What if you just do `catch { case NonFatal(th) => println(th) }` or `catch { case NonFatal(th) => th.printStackTrace }`? What will the output be? I guess now you're swallowing json4s `MappingException` with the field name somewhere.

Comment: At least here `th.getCause.getCause` you're loosing `th.getCause`

Comment: By the way (although this is not related), `Manifest` is deprecated

Comment: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html

Comment: Did you manage to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to handle to know which is field is missing while parsing Json by using json4s.

Maybe you have more complicated setting, but for example for

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._

val str = """{
             |  "name": "Json"
             |}""".stripMargin

val json = parse(str) // JObject(List((name,JString(Json))))

implicit val formats: Formats = DefaultFormats

case class MyClass(name: String, profession: String)

json.extract[MyClass]
```

it produces

```
org.json4s.MappingException: No usable value for profession
Did not find value which can be converted into java.lang.String
    at org.json4s.reflect.package$.fail(package.scala:56)
    at ...
```

with the name of missing field and if the class is just `case class MyClass(name: String)` then this produces `MyClass(Json)`.

If the class is `case class MyClass(name: String, profession: Option[String])` then this produces `MyClass(Json,None)`.

---

So normally `IllegalArgumentException` should be followed by `Caused by: org.json4s.MappingException` with the field name. I guess now you're swallowing json4s `MappingException` somewhere. Maybe in `th.getCause.getCause match ...`. It's hard to say without [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).